# Flutter - mainAxisAlignment doesn't work for a Row within a Column

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm familiar with `Row` and `Column` widget .but i'm getting stuck trying to `'float'` the content of the `Row` on the very right size of the parent `Row` within a `Column` but doesn't work

```
Row(
  //      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  mainAxisAlignment:
      isMine ? MainAxisAlignment.end : MainAxisAlignment.start,
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      margin: isMine
          ? EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0, bottom: 20.0)
          : EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 10.0,
              bottom: 20.0,
            ),
      constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: deviceSize.width * 0.85),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: isMine ? Colors.green[200] : Colors.grey[300],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(message),
          Row(
            // Horizontally
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            // Vertically
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(sentAtToSting(sentAt)),
              SizedBox(width: 10.0),
              Icon(Icons.done_all)
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

[image]

So can someone help me moving the `Row` that contains the time and the icon to the right side of the highlighted area ?

I will really appreciate your help guys !
Thanks !

Comment: Maybe just wrap the *Row* in a *Container* and do its property *margin* with *only(left: deviceSize.width * #)*

Answer (score 1):

Its because your using

```
mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min
```

Try removing main axisSize and see

Comment: Thanks ! Yeah i played around with that already , but i takes the full size of the screen (more much than the text needs ) .

Comment: So alternatively what you can do is use wrap row with a Align widget, then alignment. topRight, if it not worked try wraping row inside a container then wrap container with a Align

Comment: Okay . Please can you give me more clarification about why `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end` doesn't worked here , i usually use it and it did the trick

Comment: Its not working because mainAxis size is min, actually can't say it's not working, size is min meanit takes the contents size,

Comment: Yeah i see . Thank you !